# Stepper Motor Driver Current Regulation: Lead Acid Batteries

Tags: batteries, stepper-motor, lead-acid, stepper-driver

I'm controlling two NEMA 34 6A stepper motors through [HSS86](https://cnc4you.co.uk/resources/Servo%20Stepper%20Driver%20UK%202%20HSS86.pdf) stepper motor drivers. The drivers take AC and DC, between 20 and 80v. I'm using them to control a golf cart via remote control, and I wanted to use the golf cart's battery pack to power the steppers (4 12v lead acid batteries in series: 48v). Is there any sort of current regulation I need in between the batteries and driver? I was planning on putting a 9A fuse between each driver and the batteries, but anything beyond that?

Comment: (1) You asked: "Is there any sort of current regulation I need in between the batteries and driver?" ***My short answer is "NO"***. Your driver is an advanced microstepping driver which has over current protection and fault alarm features. (2) References: UK 2 HSS86 2-phase Hybrid Stepper Servo Driver - cnc4you:
https://cnc4you.co.uk/resources/Servo%20Stepper%20Driver%20UK%202%20HSS86.pdf.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, thanks so much for the response!